# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type {"1" : { "key": string}; "2" : { "key": string};}

Tags: typescript

I have a json file of ids as keys as such

```
"1" : { "key": "value"},
"2" : { "key": "value"},
```

I import this json in my class as data object then use the id passed to the method to retrieve the corresponding object, as such

```
funx = (key: string) {
  this.temp = data[key]
}
```

but I get the following error, that doesn't cause any runtime issues, but its blocking my unit testing and I'm getting it an error in my editor

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type {"1" : { "key": string};
"2" : { "key": string};}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try enforcing that `key` is only one of the props to the object, by doing:

```
funx = (key: keyof typeof data) {
    this.temp = data[key];
}
```

Otherwise, explicitly type your data object as an `object`, in which case all props are assumed available. I am making assumptions here because your question lacks context:

```
funx = (key: string, data: object) {
    this.temp = data[key];
}
```

The better pattern would be to type the data as `unknown`, which would then explicitly require you to cast it to a defined type (matching the shape of your JSON as closely as possible), using casting or type guards. Reference: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type